# firebase project is connected to android studio but the popup is not getting disappearing and says that you project is ready to connect with android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-assistant

[image]

The project is connected to android studio but the popup as you can see in the image is not disappearing. I tried everything, but this problem is not getting solved.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. Navigating to this [link](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/providers?utm_source=studio) and opening the project again worked.